# JQuery - If x number of classes are detected on page, then do y

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I'm making a drag-and-drop matching game for a client.

Question 1: Once all images are matched to their words, how can I make a popup appear saying "Game Over" or something similar?

Question 2: Once an image has been matched to its word, is it possible to have both the image and the word fade out of view (so the page isn't cluttered by images that have already been matched)?

Here is my Javascript:

```
$("#bottle, #butterfly").draggable({ revert: "invalid", containment: "#wrapper"});
$("#bottleDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#bottle",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.is("#bottle")){
            $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
        }
    }
});
$("#butterflyDrop").droppable({
    accept: "#butterfly",
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.draggable.is("#butterfly")){
            $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
        }
    }
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uf8Tq/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way it could be done:

```
var done = true;    
    $("#bottle, #butterfly").draggable({ 
        revert: "invalid", containment: "#wrapper",
        start: function(event, ui){
        if(!done)
            return false;
        },
        stop: function(event, ui){
            if($(".correct").length == $(".drop").length){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    alert('All items have been matched!');
                },2000);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#bottleDrop").droppable({
        accept: "#bottle",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#bottle")){
                $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
                ui.draggable.fadeOut(2000);
                $(this).fadeOut(2000);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#butterflyDrop").droppable({
        accept: "#butterfly",
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            if(ui.draggable.is("#butterfly")){
                $(this).addClass("correct").find("p").html("correct!");
                done = false;
                ui.draggable.fadeOut(2000);
                $(this).fadeOut(2000,function(){
                    done = true;
                });
            }
        }
    });
```

Example:

http://jsfiddle.net/trevordowdle/Uf8Tq/2/

Comment: @Lauren please mark this answer as accepted if it answered your question or give feedback.  Thanks

Comment: You can mark an answer as accepted by clicking the white check mark to the left of the answer.

Comment: Sorry for the delay -- This answer is perfect. Thank you, Trevor!